# AJAX Search with Laravel and Vue empty Results

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, search, vue.js

i want to build a search with ajax and vue.

So i have a model called "file" here all my files

then i have a controller called searchcontroller.php

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $files = File::where('name', $request->keywords)->get();
    return response()->json($files);
}
```

this is my route

```
Route::post('/', 'SearchController@search');
```

and i have a search.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <input type="text" v-model="keywords">
    <ul v-if="results.length > 0">
        <li v-for="result in results" :key="result.id" v-text="result.name"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            keywords: null,
            results: []
        };
    },

    watch: {
        keywords(after, before) {
            this.fetch();
        }
    },

    methods: {
        fetch() {
            axios.get('/', { params: { keywords: this.keywords } })
                .then(response => this.results = response.data)
                .catch(error => {});
        }

    }

}
</script>
```

if i type a letter the resposce work i think but it shows me 10000 list points with an emtpy result

[image]

i wanna do it like here: https://jsfiddle.net/hej7L1jy/2/

if i do:

```
console.log(this.results);
console.log(this.keywords);
```

i get for results:

Array(0)

and the keyword works

Comment: Console log your results to check if they even have a name property

Comment: i added it inside the post

Comment: No in the axios call once the response is received log it :)

Comment: axios.get('/', { params: { keywords: this.keywords } })
                .then(response => console.log(response.data))
                .catch(error => {});

Comment: Once you log the response from the axios call I'll know the structure of data we have to work with :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to Vue.js, I don't really know what I'm doing. :D When I try your code it responds with the entire HTML-Code of my page? :o

Comment: That means your response is an error or you are returning the wrong data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT IT :)

Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $files = DB::table('files')->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->get('keywords') . '%')->get();
    return response()->json($files);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/search', 'SearchController@search');
```

Vue:

```
<template>
<div>
    <input type="text" v-model="keywords">
    <ul v-if="results.length > 0">
        <li v-for="result in results" :key="result.id">{{ result.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                keywords: null,
                results: []
            };
        },

        watch: {
            keywords(after, before) {
                this.fetch();
            }
        },

        methods: {
            fetch() {
                axios.get('/search', { params: { keywords: this.keywords } })
                    .then(response => this.results = response.data)
                    .catch(error => {});
            }

        }
    }
    </script>
```

i edited the where function in my controller and i needed a "get" method , not a "post" :)

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $files = File::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->get('keywords') . '%')->get();

    return response()->json($files);
}
```

```
<template>
<div>
    <input type="text" v-model="keywords">
    <ul v-if="results.length > 0">
        <li v-for="result in results" :key="result.id">{{ result.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            keywords: null,
            results: []
        };
    },

    watch: {
        keywords(after, before) {
            this.fetch();
        }
    },

    methods: {
        fetch() {
            axios.post('/', { params: { keywords: this.keywords } })
                .then(response => this.results = response.data)
                .catch(error => {});
        }

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: now i got this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: That's an issue with your php code. Check your Laravel logs.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of much more help, there are several issues and just working through one at a time. Life of a developer.

Comment: it was a typo error, the 500 and now i dont have any errors but nothing happens either :/

Comment: Are you returning a response and is axios using post instead of get? Even if its a fake response for now.

Comment: Do you use vs code as an editor? I could jump on remote workspace otherwise we can keep at this.

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm using PHPStorm :( I've just tried it with a fake response with axios on post, it just returns one `<li>`for every letter inside the response like this: `'test'`= 4 letter = 4 `<li>`, I don't know if thats the right behaviour though.

Comment: OK good its working then now you can move on to returning a real response like you did previously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188022/discussion-between-michael-mano-and-monamuhr).